# Prove that if $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \in X$ then $\sup f(X) \leq \sup (g(X))$

Tags: real-analysis

Just writing this down for posterity. Also, I'll include a counter example to the claim that $\sup (f(x)) < \sup (g(x))$.
Suppose $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \in X$, and that their least upper bounds exist. Then $\sup f(X) \leq \sup g(x)$.

Comment: Well, since $f$ is smaller than any value given to $g$, it is also smaller than its supremum.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a domain, and $f(X)$, $g(X)$ be bounded above.

It suffices to prove that $\sup (g(X))$ (if it exists) is an upper bound of $f(X)$. Indeed, since $\sup (g(X)) \geq g(x)$ for all $x \in X$, then $\sup (g(X)) > f(x)$. Therefore, $\sup (g(X)) \geq \sup (f(X))$.

As a counter example to the claim that it must be the case that $\sup (g(X)) > \sup(f(X))$, consider the functions $f(x) = \frac{-1}{x}$ and $g(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2}$ over the domain $(1, \infty)$. Note that both of their suprema will be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that on the contrary, $\sup f(X) > \sup g(X)$. Then there is $l\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$\sup f(X) >l> \sup g(X).$$
Since $\sup f(X) >l$, there is some $x_0\in X$ such that $f(x_0)>l$. Similarly since $l> \sup g(X)$, $l>g(x)$ for $\forall x\in X$. Thus for $x=x_0$, one has
$$ f(x_0)>l>g(x_0) $$
which is against the assumption that $f(x)<g(x)$ for $\forall x\in X$.